# Copying a function result into Sub

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have the following Sub and Function and I want the result of the function to replace the contents of each Postcode. Basically the function adds a space to break the postcode up into its correct format. Everything is working fine it's just the copying of the result at the end of the function which I can't figure out

```
Sub Postcode()
Dim Postcode As Range, Postcodes As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim X As String

lastRow = Worksheets("UserInfo").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        Set Postcodes = Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("K2:K" & lastRow)

        For Each Postcode In Postcodes
            If Len(Postcode) > 6 Then
                X = Add_Space_4(Postcode.Value)
                Postcode = X
            End If

        Next Postcode


End Sub

Function Add_Space_4(Postcode As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

    For i = 1 To Len(Postcode) Step 4
        On Error Resume Next
        result = result & Left(Postcode, 4) & " "
        Postcode = Mid(Postcode, 5, Len(Postcode) - 4)
    Next i

    Postcode = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Using `Postcode` as both the name of a sub and a local variable inside the sub is needlessly confusing. Using `Integer` for `lastRow` risks overflow for no good reason. Why not just use `Long`? Also -- the indentation seems random. Why not use a consistent scheme?

Comment: Thanks for your comments John, I am still new to VBA and am still getting to grips with the basics, so it's good to get feedback like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the function to pass the value back, you need to set the value to the function name. So change it to look like this (assuming you want that last line as the passed back value):

```
Add_Space_4 = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
```